# flutter bluetooth serial communication with hc-06

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, bluetooth

I have asked about this issue multiple times but i dont seem to get the correct answer or maybe I was not providing clear explination of what is going on with me, so I will try to be as clear as I can this time.
I am building a flutter app to communicate with microcontroller via bluetooth.
I want to send numbers from the microcontroller to my flutter app. I am using flutter-bluetooth-serial package to set the bluetooth communication. So far, what I have already done is creating the connection successfully with the HC-06 bluetooth module which is connected to the microcontroller, and started listening to incoming data.

```
_getBTConnection(){

    BluetoothConnection.toAddress(widget.server.address).then((_connection){
      connection = _connection;
      isConnecting = false;
      isDisconnecting = false;
      setState(() {});

      connection.input?.listen(_onDataReceived).onDone(() {
        if(isDisconnecting){
          print("Disconnecting locally");


        }else{
          print("Disconnecting remotely");

        }
        if(mounted){
          setState(() {});
        }
        Navigator.of(context).pop();

      });

    }).catchError((error){
      Navigator.of(context).pop();

    });
  }
```

Once the app receive any data I print it on the compiler:

```
 void _onDataReceived( data  ){

    if(data != null ){
          print(data);
```

However, everytime I print the received data it comes with 2 other elements as shown bellow:

**I/flutter ( 2705): [64]**

**I/flutter ( 2705): [175, 6]**

The number I sent here is just 6 but this 64, 175 is always printed and here is another example where i sent 12:

**I/flutter ( 2705): [64]**

**I/flutter ( 2705): [175, 12]**

The second problem that I am facing is that I want to send float numbers instead of integers Here is what will happen:

In the following example, I sent 2.3 and here is what I receive:

**I/flutter ( 2705): [64]**

**I/flutter ( 2705): [171, 2]**

The different here is that when i sent integers the number before the value i sent was 175 but with float its 171 and I am not getting the full number which is 2.3 but I am getting only 2

What Can I change on my code to make it able to receive float numbers and what does this 64 and 171/175 means?

Please can someone help me, I am really struggling with these issues and non of the suggested solutions earlier worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be receiving it as ASCII codes.
Try this `String.fromCharCode(i)` 
-replace i with your value.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: void _onDataReceived(  data  ){
    String.fromCharCode(data);
    
    if(data != null ){
      print(data);

Comment: try it white printing eg: print(String.fromCharCode(data) );

Comment: alright thank you, i will try it and let you know of the reslut

Comment: I got this error: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_Uint8ArrayView' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Comment: Try ` ascii.decode(data)` in that case

Comment: Thank you so much, The first answer worked for me. I just had to change the condition from  if(data != null ) to if(data.length== 8 ). Thanks for your help and responses.

Comment: Upvoting and ticking as answered makes the right answer more visible to other help sellers.